# Testar compatibilidade projeto angular em vários navegadores

Tags: javascript, angularjs, navegador-de-internet

Tenho uma aplicação web feita com AngularJS v1.5.8 e estou preocupado com questão de compatibilidade, porém não pretendo baixar diversos browsers e sair testando um por um em diferentes versões. Quero saber se existe alguma ferramenta que automatize essa tarefa árdua de testar a compatibilidade em diversos browsers, sendo que o projeto ainda não foi pra produção.

Comment: Quando eu tenho duvida sobre a compatibilidade de alguma função ou atributo css sobre ele ser compatível, eu confiro por aqui: http://caniuse.com/

Comment: A aplicação que eu pretendo testar é bem complexa, sair verificando a compatibilidade um por um vai ser muito trabalhoso, mas valeu pela dica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem muitas ferramentas para teste de compatibilidade em navegadores. Algumas das mais utilizadas são:

- [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/)
- [GhostLab](https://www.vanamco.com/ghostlab/)
- [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/)